# IDE suggests the code, but I cannot understand

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript code like as follows

```
   if (jQuery("#" + formId).valid()) {
        status = true;
   } else {
        status = false;
   }
```

If my form is valid according to jquery validation then the status will be true else it will be false. So far it is fine.
IDE suggests to code like

```
status = !!jQuery("#" + formId).valid();
```

Can someone explain me what does this do? If it is correct how? I have tried to understand but unable to make it.

Comment: The double she-bang is useless

Comment: Just use `status = jQuery("#" + formId).valid();`

Comment: `!!` is used to first coerce the value to a boolean (assuming it wasn't already) and then invert it. As `valid()` is already a boolean, you can remove that operator and just use `status = $('#' + formId).valid();`

Comment: got it. Thank you so much.